# Spring Mvc display session in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session

I have created a simple shopping cart project using spring framework. I've created a button add to cart so that when clicked it will create session of that item. I have following codes

```
<button href="/addcart/1">Add to button</button>
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/addcart/{id}")
public ModelAndView goCart(@PathVariable("id")int id,HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    List<CartItem> cart = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
    cart.add(new CartItem(productService.findProductCart(id),1));
    session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("cart");
    return model;
}
```

this is my CartItem class

```
public class CartItem {

    private List<Product> product;
    private int quantity;


    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public CartItem(List<Product> product, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public CartItem() {
        super();
    }


}
```

this is my Product class

```
public class Product {

private int pid;
private String productName;
private int unitPrice;

public int getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(int pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}


public int getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(int unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}
}
```

I've a productServiceImpl class of this productDaoImpl

```
@Override
    public List<Product> findProductCart(int id) {
        List<Product> cartProduct = new ArrayList<Product>();
        String sql = "select * from product where pid= " + id;
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        cartProduct = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ProductRowMapper());
        return cartProduct;
    }
```

I've view in jsp with following code

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionScope.cart}">
        <li>${item.quantity}</li>
        <li>${item}</li>
    </c:forEach>
```

this give

```
1
com.sparktronix.mvc.domain.CartItem@344e01
```

How to display session value productname and unitprice? Any suggestion are welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you get when you print `${item.product[0].productName}` and `${item.product[0].unitPrice}` inside jsp forEach loop?

Comment: You can try this `<c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionScope.cart}">
        <li>${item.quantity}</li>
       <c:forEach items = "${item.product}" var="product">
           <li>${product.productName}</li>
           <li>${product.unitPrice}</li>
       </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>` to print iteratively

Comment: @harshavmb thank  you 
it solved my issue

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! You just have to get the `product` object from `sessionScope` and iterate once again like below.

```
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionScope.cart}">
      <li>${item.quantity}</li>
        <c:forEach items = "${item.product}" var="product"> 
            <li>${product.productName}</li>
            <li>${product.unitPrice}</li>
        </c:forEach> 
    </c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps!